# jquery trigger change with chained ajax select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a chanied select in this way and works very well.

```
$(function() {

  /**
   * Chained Select (id_foo)
   *
   * @method on change
   */
  $('select[name="id_foo"]').on('change', function() {
      var id_foo = $("option:selected", this).prop("value");
      $.ajax({
          type    : "POST",
          url       : ajax.php,
          data    : { id_foo: id_foo },
          success : function(data) {
              $('select[name="id_bar"]').html(data);
          }
      });
  });

}); /* END */
```

HTML

```
<select name="id_foo">
   <option value="1">one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="id_bar">
</select>
```

AJAX.PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['id_foo'])){
   $obj->selectBar($_POST['id_foo']);
}
```

Now I'd like to use trigger function to simulate on change event in this way

```
$(function() {

  $('select[name="id_foo"]').val('2').trigger('change');

  /**
   * Chained Select (id_foo)
   *
   * @method on change
   */
   $('select[name="id_foo"]').on('change', function() {
   ...
   ...
```

But with no success. The value of select is 2 but the trigger event does nothing.
How could I solve? thank you

Comment: What is a "chained ajax select"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 You change one select and the change fills another select

Comment: Best to avoid "chained" in that context as the word has a specific meaning in javascript/jQuery - viz "method chaining".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) does not return a jQuery object.

Instead do

```
$(function() {
  var $sel = $('select[name="id_foo"]');
  $sel.on('change', function() {
    var id_foo = this.value;
    $.ajax({
      type    : "POST",
      url       : ajax.php,
      data    : { id_foo: id_foo },
      success : function(data) {
          $('select[name="id_bar"]').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
  $sel.val('2');
  $sel.change();
});
```

Comment: I separated function val and function change and placed under and it works perfectly. Thank You!