# How to trigger a method change() in jQuery which launch ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a select item html with a list of departement.
When I select one (method "change"), it launch an ajax request in jquery, that will display in another select input, a list of cities taken from a database.

Everything works fine, but I have a case where I want to be able to get back what values are stored for departement and ville select items, and at the same time I want to be able to modify it.

I tried to use jQuery .trigger("change"), but it doesn't get into my change function.

I tried to do as it's written here, but there was no difference. 
[jquery trigger change with chained ajax select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963159/jquery-trigger-change-with-chained-ajax-select)

My html file :

```
<div class="inscriptionForm">
    <label for="departement">Département :</label>
    <select name="departement" id="departement" required="required">
        <option value="">Choisissez un département</option>
        <c:forEach items="${departements}" var="departement">
            <option value="${departement.code}">${departement.code} - <c:out value="${departement.nom}"/></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="inscriptionForm">
    <label for="ville">Ville :</label>
    <select name="ville" id="ville" required="required">
        <option value="">Choisissez une ville</option>
        <c:forEach items="${villes}" var="ville">
            <option value="${ville.id}"><c:out value="${ville.nom}"/></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>
```

My Jquery methods :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var departement = ${spot.departement.code};
        var ville = ${spot.ville.id};
        $("#departement option[value="+departement+"]").prop('selected', true);
        $('#departement').trigger("change");
        $("#ville option[value="+ville+"]").prop('selected', true);

        $('#departement').change(function() {
            var choixDep = $('#departement').val();
            $.getJSON("choixDepartement.do",{codeDep: choixDep},
                function (data) {
                    $("#ville").empty();
                    var option = "<option value=''>Choisissez une ville</option>";
                    $("#ville").append(option);
                    $.each( data, function(key, val) {
                        .....
                       ajax callback treatment
                       ........
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

I don't understand why it doesn't get into the method `.change();`.

Comment: You call `trigger('change')` before you define the event handler. Change the order around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var departement = ${spot.departement.code};
    var ville = ${spot.ville.id};
    $("#departement option[value="+departement+"]").prop('selected', true);

    $("#ville option[value="+ville+"]").prop('selected', true);

    $('#departement').change(function() {
        var choixDep = $('#departement').val();
        $.getJSON("choixDepartement.do",{codeDep: choixDep},
            function (data) {
                $("#ville").empty();
                var option = "<option value=''>Choisissez une ville</option>";
                $("#ville").append(option);
                $.each( data, function(key, val) {
                    .....
                   ajax callback treatment
                   ........
                });
            }
        );
    });
    $('#departement').trigger("change");
});
```

In Jquery we should define event first then we need to trigger

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know that. It works now, but i encounter another problem. Once my departement element is loaded, the ajax request is sent and load the ville element. If i try to do ```$("#ville option[value="+ville+"]").prop('selected', true);``` after my ```$('#departement').trigger("change");```, it is executed before. So i can't get my ville option selected, cause it is empty at that moment*

Comment: okay it that case add your trigger code in setTimeout method in your case the last line will look something like this `setTimeout(function(){ $('#departement').trigger("change");  },0);`

Answer (score 1):

To be executed, an `eventListener` must be declared before the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Once again thank you. 
It's working after declaring the change() function before,
but I still don't figure out how to select a value in my "ville" option list, even with your advice with the setTimeout to 0.
The execution order seems pretty strange to me. I probably don't know jQuery enough. So far my code looks like that, and the ville list stay with no value selected.

```
    var departement =${spot.departement.code};
    var ville =${spot.ville.id};

    $("#departement option[value="+departement+"]").prop('selected', true);

    alert(departement);
    alert(ville);

        $('#departement').change(function() {
            var choixDep = $('#departement').val();
            $.getJSON("choixDepartement.do",{codeDep: choixDep},
                function (data) {
                    $("#ville").empty();
                    var option = "<option value=''>Choisissez une ville</option>";
                    $("#ville").append(option);
                    $.each( data, function(key, val) {
                        var valToString = val.toString();
                        var valToArray = valToString.split(",");
                        var option = "<option value=" + valToArray[0] + ">" + valToArray[1] + "</option>";
                        $("#ville").append(option);
                    });
                }
            );
        });

        setTimeout(function(){$('#departement').trigger("change");},0);

        $("#ville option[value="+ville+"]").prop('selected', true);
```

My ville value, and the list is there, but the value doesn't get selected

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the full answer for my problem.
First obviously it was the problem of declaration order. Function .change() should have been declared before being called.
But then it was not working cause the Ajax request was taking a certain amount of time time, and the `$("#ville option[value="+ville+"]").prop('selected', true);`was executed bbefore the request send the result. So i just put this line after the ajax request and now it's working properly.
So here is the final code :

```
       var departement =${spot.departement.code};

       $('#departement').change(function() {
            var choixDep = $('#departement').val();
            $.getJSON("choixDepartement.do",{codeDep: choixDep},
                function (data) {
                    $("#ville").empty();
                    var option = "<option value=''>Choisissez une ville</option>";
                    $("#ville").append(option);
                    $.each( data, function(key, val) {
                        var valToString = val.toString();
                        var valToArray = valToString.split(",");
                        var option = "<option value=" + valToArray[0] + ">" + valToArray[1] + "</option>";
                        $("#ville").append(option);
                    });
                    $("#ville option[value="+ville+"]").prop('selected', true);
                }
            );
        });

        $("#departement option[value="+departement+"]").prop('selected', true);

        $('#departement').trigger("change");
```